# What is considered normal behavior for iOS app memory usage?

Tags: ios, memory, memory-management, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm developing an application using `Xamarin.iOS`. It is common knowledge, that its memory is handled very inefficiently and leaks are almost inevitable. That's why I'm trying to be as careful as possible and not to do anything stupid: no circular dependencies, no event listeners left unremoved, etc. I'm using `Instruments` to monitor resources used by my app. I have a following app design:
There is a `UIViewControllerA` which has a `UITableView` and a couple of labels/buttons. When you press on any of three table entries, you're navigated to `UIViewControllerB`, `UIViewControllerC`, `UIViewControllerD` respectively. It also makes a couple of HTTP requests. Each of the controllers also have labels, graphics, tables, scrollviews, buttons etc, and they also make HTTP requests. I'm testing my app by going from `UIViewControllerA` to those three and back, randomly. Meanwhile, I can see `Real Memory` column of Instrument's Resource Monitor increase by 1-2MB with every new appearance of new UIViewControllers. It never goes down. Since I don't really know, how memory should behave and since there is virtually no information on that topic, I don't know if this is considered to be a normal behavior for an iOS app. Is it okay? I do realize that my question is very vague, but I need to know if I need to pay attention to those "signs".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without deeper knowledge of your code and what exactly it is doing, I would say it is not a normal behavior. If you switch between ControllerA, B and back to A it should also free up some memory. A good memory usage should look like a sawblade with up and downs.

The general problem is that the GC may not free up the memory immediately. If you have memory-heavy operations like image-processing you could consider to make use of `GC.Collect()` - but that should be your last option - to force a collection and free up some memory.

In addition to Instruments, which I also use heavily to profile my apps, is the Xamarin Profiler to gain more insights of what is still alive and keeps some references. If for some reason you can not use Xamarin Profiler use the build in tool called Heap Shot.